# How to remove "Archives" after category name?

Tags: archives

There are many similar questions, but none of them have exactly the same issue as I do. Unfortunately the solutions suggested there have not fixed my issue.

After selecting a category in my Shop page, the page title turns into "Categoryname Archives - Storename". I would like to remove the "Archives" part from the title, or atleast translate it. I have not found a way to translate or remove it. I am using Loco Translate for my translation needs.

All links with examples:
https://www.prindistuudio.ee/pood/ - Our Store page.
https://www.prindistuudio.ee/kategooria/kruusid/ - A category named "Kruusid" is selected, the title is incorrect.

Is this a theme, SEO or some other problem? I have tried some suggestions to make changes in Yoast SEO, but for that I would need to change a certain page's SEO options. I do not know which page is handling the category selection (so https://www.prindistuudio.ee/kategooria/categoryname).

Any advice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should be Yoast SEO related.

In your WordPress admin dashboard navigate to **SEO** -> **Search Appearance**.

Then, on the **Taxonomies** tab you can edit the "Archives" text (and many other strings).

Comment: I would like to see the reason for downvoting this post, because this almost certainly is the correct answer.